# Why the mic is attenuated until there's no sound at all?

Tags: windows-10, microphone

My hardware is a mother an Asus ROG STRIX B450-F GAMING and just buyed a new condenser mic that I plugged in pink female connector.
I tested with Audacity and work for a couple of seconds, then is attenuated, then is muted, and the signal is no that high, never get the red zone.
If I make no noise for a couple of seconds the volume gets back to normal level.

I tried with +30dB, +20dB, +10dB and 0dB and is mostly the same result.
Also I tried enabling and disabling the noise cancelling from Realtek Audio Administrator with same results.

Then I plugged the mic in an external cheap USB audio board and works ok, so I think is something related with the motherboard, which is new also.

Any idea about what can be happening?